# Is this string of $_FILES safe to use?

Tags: php

Hi i have a question about this string,

My teacher says this string isn't safe to use in my php project.

this is the string:

```
if (filter_var_array($_FILES['evidence']) && $_FILES['evidence']['size'] !== 0)
```

Can somebody help me to confirm if its safe to use or not.

this is the full code:

```
if (filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, 'submit')) {

    $errors = []; // Store errors here.

    if (filter_var_array($_FILES['evidence']) && $_FILES['evidence']['size'] !== 0) { // controleren / niet veilig???

        $fileExtensionsAllowed = ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'svg', 'doc', 'docx', 'pdf']; // These will be the only file extensions allowed.

        $fileName = $_FILES['evidence']['name'];
        $fileSize = $_FILES['evidence']['size'];
        $fileTmpName  = $_FILES['evidence']['tmp_name'];
        $fileType = $_FILES['evidence']['type'];
        $fileExtension = explode(".", $fileName);
        $fileExtension = end($fileExtension);

        $randomFilename = $model->str_random() . '.' . $fileExtension;

        $uploadPath = PLUGIN_UPLOADS_DIR . '/submissions/' . $randomFilename;

        if (!in_array($fileExtension, $fileExtensionsAllowed)) {
            $errors[] = "Upload een jpg, jpeg, svg, png, doc, docx of pdf.";
        }

        if ($fileSize > 50000000) {
            $errors[] = "Maximaal 50 mb mag geupload worden.";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why does your teacher say it is not safe? What have they taught you is unsafe about it?

Comment: Why are you trying to use  `filter_var_array` here? What exactly are you trying to do? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Without further context, this is mostly a code smell. It's totally unclear what goal `filter_var_array()` attempts to accomplish and checking `size` but not `error` is always suspicious.

Comment: i first used isset $_FILES but he said it not good because it wasnt save to use in term of other coders could see your data or something like that.